Samsung Phones and the new MMI Apps installed that cannot be turned off
I was just wondering how Samsung or Google can force people to participate in the MMI group study without the customer's permission? Will I have to purchase from a different phone service to opt out of this? Every call is now being recorded and shared for discussions.
Thank you for any advice! 

Possibly related: What is "MMI Group" app?

Looks like this is limited to Samsung devices. Google doesn't seem to have anything to do with it.
